# Appium test shows "Automation Running" overlay on iOS15 - How can I get rid of it?

Tags: automation, appium, overlay, ios15

I am using a tool to automate tests on iPhones. The tool uses Appium as the test framework. In iOS version 15, the screen shows a dark overlay with the text "Automation Running". I am aware that this does not affect the test at all.

However, my problem is that I use a camera placed in front of the mobile phone to capture the screen and do some checks on the captured video. I have to use the camera itself since I run tests on OTT applications and there is no way to capture the video using software mechanisms because of DRM protection. This "Automation Running" overlay messes up with the checks that I am running on the video captured through the camera.

Is there any way to get rid of this overlay in iOS15 when we run Appium based tests?

Answer (score 3):

After extensive exploration, I have come to the conclusion that there is no way this overlay can be gotten rid of unless Apple wants to.